# Adding/Subtracting Hexadecimals

Tags: python

How can I add/subtract hexadecimal's that the user inputs?

Like:

```
basehex = input()
sechex = input()

sum = hex(basehex - sechex)



print(sum)
```

I get: *TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'*

How do I do this? Must I convert them to *int*? Then I can't have them as hex (0xFFFFFF)...?

The only way I can do it is:

```
basehex = int('255')
sechex = int('255')

sum = hex(basehex - sechex)



print(sum)
```

But this requires me to enter basehex/sechex as numbers, since int won't take it otherwise:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ff'
```

Thanks :)

Comment: If you want a base other than 10, you need to explicitly pass the [`base` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to `int`.

Comment: You're conflicting variable types. Your input comes in as a string which can't do arithmetic, which is why you convert it to an integer using `int`. From there you can print the result in hex again (it's a _representation_) by doing `print(hex(sum))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to @Peri461

```
basehex = input()
sechex = input()

basehexin = int(basehex, 16)
sechexin = int(sechex, 16)



sum = basehexin - sechexin



print(hex(sum))
```

This code will do it, by converting the hexadecimals to decimals, subtracting them, then converting(representing) them to hexadecimals again.

Comment: Note that `int` does not convert hexadecimal to decimal; it converts a string to an integer, which is stored internally in binary, not decimal. If you _display_ that integer at the prompt, e.g., by printing it, you're doing a conversion back from integer to string; that's the only place that decimal comes into the picture.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a '+' operator instead of '-' while evaluating ```sum```?

Answer (score 0):

Zombie! but this was the first google hit so I am adding on here.

If you can convince the user to enter in hex format (0x100) you can just do normal math.

```
basenum = 0x100
addnum =0x10
total = basenum + addnum
```